# A chunk of code not being executed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to embed a cropper through a library in the Main activity of ABBYY Cloud OCR sample code. But no matter how hard I try, instead of executing the crop-code, it always jumps on to the next activity. Why is this happening?

```
package bahadur.translateit;

import abbyy.ocrsdk.android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.net.*;

import java.io.*;

 import eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
private final int SELECT_FILE = 1; 

private String resultUrl = "result.txt";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void captureImageFromSdCard( View view ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
}

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "TranlateIt!");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "image.jpg" );

    return mediaFile;
}

public void captureImageFromCamera( View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
} 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;

    String imageFilePath = null;

    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        imageFilePath = getOutputMediaFileUri().getPath();
```

// the following code for crop does not execute

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, imageFilePath);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 0);
        intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 0);





        break;
    case SELECT_FILE: 
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        imageFilePath = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
```

// same goes for the following chunk of code

```
Intent intet = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
intet.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, imageFilePath);
intet.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

            intet.putExtra("outputX", 200); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
            intet.putExtra("outputY", 150); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
            intet.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 0);
            intet.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 0);



        break;
    }
```

this runs instead

```
    String lastfilepath = imageFilePath;

    //Remove output file
    deleteFile(resultUrl);

    Intent results = new Intent( this, ResultsActivity.class);
    results.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH", lastfilepath);
    results.putExtra("RESULT_PATH", resultUrl);
    startActivity(results);

} 

}
```

Comment: you're building the intent, but not using it for anything. you need a call to startActivity() somewhere in the case statement.

Comment: @Dave The intent is of course used to send the strings to the next activity - ResultsActivity.

Comment: I understand that part, but you have to look at the scope of the intent you create inside each case statement. you create an Intent later and call startActivity on it, but you only build the earlier intent objects.  just instantiating an intent doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my comments, i mean somethign like this:

```
case TAKE_PICTURE:
    imageFilePath = getOutputMediaFileUri().getPath();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, imageFilePath);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 150); //Set this to define the max size of the output bitmap
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 0);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 0);
    startActivity(intent);// THIS is the line you are missing!
```